# Необработанное исключение: System.FormatException

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double s = 0, sg = 0, sw; 
            int n = 0, k = 0, a, b, c, d;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите a, для окончания - 6");
                a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (a >= 6) break;
                Console.WriteLine("Введите b");
                b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Введите c");
                c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Введите d");
                d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                s = (a + b + c + d) / 4;
                sg = sg + s;
                n = n + 1;
                if (s < 3) k++;
            } while (a < 6);
            sw = sg / n;
            Console.WriteLine("Количество неуспевающих студентов k={0:d}", k);
            Console.WriteLine("Средний балл группы sw={1:f2}", sw);
        }
    }
}
```

Никак не могу найти, в чем проблема... Что бы ни делал, все время выдает"Индекс (отсчитываемый от нуля) должен быть больше или равен нулю, но меньше размера списка аргументов"

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш код вообще в принципе компилируется?

Comment: `{1:f2}` - здесь должен быть ноль вместо единицы.

Comment: `sw={1:f2}"` попробуйте `sw={0:f2}"`

Comment: тут помимо форматов, автор пытается записать double в int без явного приведения типов

Comment: и double с int приводятся некорректно

Answer (score 2):

```
        double s = 0, sg = 0, sw = 0;
        double n = 0, k = 0, a, b, c, d;

        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите a, для окончания - 6");
            a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a >= 6) break;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите b");
            b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите c");
            c = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите d");
            d = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            s = (a + b + c + d) / 4;
            sg = sg + s;
            n = n + 1;
            if (s < 3) k++;
        }
        sw = sg == 0 && n == 0 || n == 0 ? 0 : sg / n;

        Console.WriteLine("Количество неуспевающих студентов k={0}\nСредний балл группы sw={1}", k, sw);
        Console.ReadKey();
```